# Get number of row and display

Tags: php, count, row

How to get total number of row in database via php and display it?I've done it in phpmyadmin using COUNT(column_name) FROM (table_name) but I got confuse when applying using php. Sorry for my silly question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do something like this:

```
 <?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

    /* check connection */
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }

    if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT Code, Name FROM Country ORDER BY Name")) {

        /* determine number of rows result set */
        $row_cnt = $result->num_rows;

        printf("Result set has %d rows.\n", $row_cnt);

        /* close result set */
        $result->close();
    }

    /* close connection */
    $mysqli->close();
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php    
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table`") or die(mysql_error());

    echo mysql_num_rows($sql);
?>
```